# Style Scite with Lua?

Tags: lua, scite

I would like to style Scite, so it starts up with whatever is the default style - but then I would want to change to a different style to a dark one by running a command. So, after some digging, I got to this script in `sciteLuaFunctions.lua` which I mapped to a command in Tools menu:

```lua
  -- http://scite.ruteam.ru/archive/1.59
local function encodeRGB(color)
  if string.sub(color,1,1)=="#" and string.len(color)>6 then
    return tonumber(string.sub(color,6,7)..string.sub(color,4,5)..string.sub(color,2,3), 16)
  else
    return color
  end
end

function ChangeToDarkTheme()
  -- http://www.scintilla.org/PaneAPI.html
  -- http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEFAQ.html " How do I change SciTE to use black as the background colour?"
  -- http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html
  -- color calculation works like this:
--~   mycolorRGB = { r = 100, g = 100, b = 100 }                        -- ok
--~   mycolor = (mycolorRGB.r+(mycolorRGB.g*256)+(mycolorRGB.b*65536))  -- ok
  -- but also can use encodeRGB:
  myBackgroundColor = encodeRGB("#282C34")
  editor.StyleBack[32] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background, but where there no text
  editor.StyleBack[33] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background of line numbers
end
```

Then, when I run this command, I get something like this:

[image: scite-bckg]

The problem is:

- The default background changes only the background not taken up by (text) characters (including linefeeds/empty lines); I would like to modify this background color too

  - EDIT: Thanks to comment by @EgorSkriptunoff, managed to get (by manually experimenting with values) the entire background (at least while editing `sciteLuaFunctions.lua`, so for `lua` syntax coloring, but also for `cpp` it works) in the same color with this:

    ```
    editor.StyleBack[32] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background, but where there no text
    editor.StyleBack[33] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background of line numbers
    editor.StyleBack[0] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background of whitespace/indents
    editor.StyleBack[2] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background of commented lines
    editor.StyleBack[4] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background of numbers at uncommented lines
    editor.StyleBack[5] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background of reserved keywords (function) at uncommented lines
    editor.StyleBack[6] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background of strings ("...") at uncommented lines
    editor.StyleBack[10] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background of equal signs, etc at uncommented lines
    editor.StyleBack[11] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background of regular variables at uncommented lines
    editor.StyleBack[14] = myBackgroundColor -- mods background of predef functions (string.sub) at uncommented lines
    ```

    ... except, I cannot tell where are the styles 2, 4, 5, 6 etc documented, as they are not in the FAQ or the other docs linked in the snippet above ?! So is there a list of numeric styles somewhere, and what they change?
- If I then open a new tab, the new styling disappears - if I go back to the previous tab, the new styling disappears as well; I would instead like for the style to persist until either explicitly reset by a script, or until shutdown.

Is it possible to achieve these with a Lua script, and if so, how?

Comment: Thanks @EgorSkriptunoff - already have that linked in the code; was wondering on what to do from lua, cheers!

Comment: `for i = 0, 63 do editor.StyleBack[i] = 0x282C34 end`

Comment: Many thanks, @EgorSkriptunoff - that worked -- except the vertical line separating the line numbers and the text area does not change its background color. I experimented a bit with the values, and it seems not all numeric styles from 0 to 63 need to be changed; so I edited my OP above.. Cheers!

Comment: The set of styles depends on the language of the file being edited (each `.properties` file defines its own styles, styles 0-31 are language-specific).

Comment: `props["fold.margin.colour"]=0x282C34; props["fold.margin.highlight.colour"]=0x282C34`